# Updating phone-firmware based on phone carrier

Tags: updates, carriers

A while ago I bought a Samsung Galaxy S6 Edge with a a dutch site called BelSimpel. This phone came with an contract from a dutch carrier called "Simpel", which is using the T-Mobile network.

When the phone arrived, it was still sealed and wasn't a dutch device based on the EAN number, it was delivered like buying a phone without a contract. A week later my sim-card came in, from the Simpel provider, so this was a SIM-only contract.

The phone is originally from Czech Republic.

When checking for updates on the [live samsung updates feed](http://live.samsung-updates.com/index.php?device=SM-G925F) for my phone, I see all updates getting released for a specific region (per provider per region).

Since my phone was delivered without a contract, how are updates getting released for my phone? Because I have a dutch carrier, using the T-Mobile network.

Comment: If they have BestBuy in your area, they will update your phone for free at their Samsung Store.

Comment: @MichelfrancisBustillos We don't have that store around here, but I know how to update my phone myself. The problem is that I didn't receive it yet, and asking about it when I can determine when it will come for my phone.

Comment: In my experience, only phones purchased from a carrier and used on that carrier received OTA updates, meaning you will have to update it yourself.

Comment: Well ofcourse I'm going to have to update it myself. But i'm assuming this can just go through the phone itself? I've had a update to 5.1.1 aswell, which I didn't have to flash or anything.

Comment: What do you mean, "through the phone itself"? Are you referring to OTA updates (pushed by the carrier)? If not, how are you updating?

Comment: What I mean by "through the phone itself" is just going to my Settings, tapping on "About phone" and tapping Software-update. I have no idea if this relates to OTA updates.

Comment: When you do that, it sends a request to the carrier checking for an upgrade. Since the phone was not purchased from the carrier, there is a high probability that the request will error or that no updates will be given (this is so people cannot use a carrier just for updates).

Comment: @MichelfrancisBustillos Well, I have a SIM-only contract here connected to a carrier. Where did I get android 5.1.1 from then? Plus, where am I going to update android 6 from then?

Comment: I am not sure regarding the source of the update since I am only familiar with American carriers. You could always download the Android 6.x.x ROM and flash it to your device.

Comment: @MichelfrancisBustillos I think that's kind of dangerous cause it will remove my warranty. While samsung is already rolling out the update for more S6 Edge's?

Comment: Depending on where you bought the device from and who unlocked it (best case is it was factory-unlocked and a resale), your warranty might be already void. Besides OTA updates, or a Samsung store, a flash is most likely the only way to update.

Comment: @MichelfrancisBustillos Well, a dutch company called BelSimpel. It's an original samsung device, i've had the IMEI checked. But since I have a contract, only a SIM-only, why can't i get OTA off that?

Comment: It may be original Samsung, but that doesn't mean that someone didn't unlock it /after/ the factory, voiding any warranty. You can't get an OTA update since the phone is not from the carrier, so their software is not preinstalled.

Comment: @MichelfrancisBustillos Can I check if the phone is unlocked? Or attached to a carrier.

Comment: If you were able to use your SIM card then it is unlocked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get the latest firmware for your Samsung Android device, head over to http://sammobile.com/firmwares/ and type in your Model number found in

```
Settings->Device Information (or maybe one of the subcategories like Software information)
```

It can also be found at the beginning of either `Baseband` or sometimes `Build number`. As a last resort the box your phone came in has that information on the little sticker with the three barcodes.

Given that you linked the international, unbranded S6 Edge (SM-G925F), I guess your device is unbranded. You will get updates via OTA directly from Samsung (no carrier in between you and the stock firmware) so watch out for any carrier specific firmware. They may replace parts of the firmware with their branding and their bloatware.

Any stock firmware for the SM-G925F will work as long as you don't intend to downgrade.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I still don't get it. Since my device is _international_ and _unbranded_ am i forced to actually download a ROM file and flash my phone?

Comment: @Bas No, you are not. You can simply wait until the update is available via OTA in your country.

Comment: Alright, but that's just the thing actually. I'm checking the live.samsung-updates daily, and now I even saw 6.0.1 getting release for the Netherlands (see http://puu.sh/nuv2v/d279b6cb3d.png). Also another one for Netherlands, t-mobile. How does it come I didn't receive it yet?

Comment: @Bas updates are rolled out in waves. If you haven't received it in about a week, flash it manually.

Comment: Thanks. I'll wait a week from now. Isn't it that I have to wait for the update to come out in  Czech Republic right now?